# Kotlin CoroutineScope.lambda notation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Recently, I came across the following code:

```
runWithObject(block: suspend CoroutineScope.(myObject: MyClass) -> Unit) {
   ...
   myObject?.let { runBlocking(myDispatcher) { block(it) } }
   ...
}
```

Can someone explain to me what the argument type, CoroutineScope.(myObject: MyClass) -> Unit means (and some documentation if possible)? Since I'm not sure what this is, I don't even know how to ask Google XD

It seems like the argument is a block of code that should be run if myObject is non-null. But what's the `CoroutineScope.` for? Does it mean that the function is something that can only be run in coroutines?

Answer (score 1):

It's a function receiver, explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types). Inside the lambda that you pass to this higher-order function, `this` is the receiver.

In this case, it means that inside the lambda, you can freely call functions that are members of CoroutineScope (like `launch`, `async`, `cancel` and the `coroutineContext` property) without specifying the scope.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your help, this way of writing inspired me to write more flexible coroutine code!